# How to attribute an image in a variable in unix inside a python script

Tags: python, unix, os.system

I have this code:

```
os.system('convert xc:red xc:black xc:white +append swatch.png')
os.system('convert red_1.jpg +dither -remap swatch.png start.png')
```

In first line I create a saved colored Image like this:

But I would like just to attribute this image a variable, without open this image again, do this directly. Something like this, in a simple way:

```
os.system('convert xc:red xc:black xc:white +append my_image')
```

In second line, I need to read the images, I would like to atribute the variables directly too, like this:

```
os.system('convert input_image_1 +dither -remap input_image_2 output_image')
```

I am doing several processes of an image, and I would not like to need to save an image and then open it again, I would like to do the process directly, is it possible?

Comment: Don't use `os.system`. Use `subprocess.call`. `os.system` both has very limited power _and_ creates serious security bugs.

Comment: That said, I don't know what you mean by "attribute" at all in this context. Is `my_image` supposed to be a Python variable? What _exactly_ are its contents?

Comment: Note that all invocation of subprocesses goes through either the fork+execv interface or something higher-level and roughly equivalent in power. That means that all you can pass on a command line are _strings_. Those can be strings that refer to filenames where the filename is something like a pipe or FIFO, but they're still necessarily strings.

Comment: An image. Just this.

Comment: That doesn't tell me anything. The _filename_ of an image? _Raw binary data_ of an image? Some kind of Python object representing an image? (What kind?)

Comment: In general, btw, I'd suggest using a native Python library in the first place instead of calling the command-line `convert` at all. If you're using the ImageMagick version of `convert`, f/e, they have a "PythonMagick" binding that gives you a native API for it.

Comment: Sorry, I will try another approach. I'm not able to explain. Thanks for your time. And so sorry. @Charles Duffy.

Comment: Do you know how to make the thing you're trying to do work in a non-Python language? If you can connect two `convert`s together the way you want in shell (say, with process substitution), I can tell you how to do the same thing in Python.

Comment: (to explain why passing raw binary data on a command line is a problem, by the way -- first, there's a limit, typically somewhere between 128KB and 256KB, on total length of the command line + the environment; second, both command line arguments and environment variables are passed by C strings, which are NUL terminated, so they can't contain binary 0s. That's why it's normal for folks to pass the name of a pipe or FIFO that the parent process is reading from or writing to as a command-line argument, and put data in or read it from that pipe or FIFO).

Comment: You could look into a library called [pillow](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/), which allows you to manipulate images without using an external process.

Comment: I recommend doing this in `bash` or `PowerShell` directly or find a library to do it in python rather than using `os.system()`.

Comment: It is probably possible to do your requested multiple operations in one go, but you need to click [edit] and say, in concrete terms, what you actually want to do. I can see you are making a colour-swatch and mapping an image to that swatch, but you seem to want to do something else too - just you don't say what.

Comment: Maybe add the 2-3 separate commands you know from the Terminal, then we can combine them for you.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy. Actually I have an Image, and I would like pattern my image with three default pixel colors red, white and black

Answer (score 0):

I used a python code as suggested:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Load image
img = cv2.imread('marmoreio_red_1.jpg')


# Define standard colors
colors = [(0, 0, 0), (255, 255, 255), (0, 0, 255)]  # black, white, red

# Define color mapping function as a lambda function
map_colors = lambda pixel: colors[np.argmin([np.linalg.norm(np.array(pixel) - np.array(color)) for color in colors])]

# Map the colors in the image using the color mapping function
for i in range(img.shape[0]):
    for j in range(img.shape[1]):
        img[i, j] = map_colors(img[i, j])

# Display and save the resulting image
cv2.imshow("Standardized Image", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

cv2.imwrite("standardized_image.png", img)
```